# Where are the locations of Tarohne's tomes?

Tags: dragon-age-2

In Dragon Age 2, where are Tarohne's tomes hidden? It's the Sidequest "Forbidden Knowledge" in Act 2.

I found two so far, in the Chantry and in the Viscount's Keep. How many are there and where are they located?

What happens if you read them / destroy them / take them with you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are initially five tomes, but because I'm too lazy to explain where they are, I'll simply quote a [source](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Forbidden_Knowledge) that provides the required information:

> - In **Abandoned Thaig**, the entrance (known as "Recently Opened Passage") is at the west end of **Sundermount**, in a corner left of the north-western exit, accessible only in Act II. The tome is found in the main room of the thaig next to the Nexus Golem (for the battle in this room, see "strategy" section in Abandoned Thaig page).
> - A cave at the east end of **The Bone Pit** (outside the mine). Inside the location is called "Cave"
> - A cave in the northern middle parts of **The Wounded Coast**. It should be named "The Dank Cave" and is not marked on your map. Note that this cave is inaccessible later in the game.
> - In The **Chantry**, on a table from the southern stairs, second floor.
> - In the **Viscount's Keep**, eastern part on a table near the throne.

After which you are required to find a sixth tome:

> ... it can be found in The **Forgotten Lair**, which is an area in **Darktown** next to the entrance. Note that you may come across a locked door and will need a Rogue to unlock it,

---

Again, the same [source](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Forbidden_Knowledge) will let you verify, but here's my trimmed down version of what your options are once you reach each book (including the last one):

**Destroy book**:

- -10 rivalry with Merrill

**Read book**: *you only get these effects the first time you choose these option*

- Accept deal:

  - +5 friendship with Merrill
  - Greater Tome of the Mortal Vessel
  - +2 attribute points
- Take book:

  - +5 friendship with Merrill

**Take book**:

- Receive a Book of Forbidden Lore trash item to sell (so a little cash, nothing else).

I think reading or taking any of the first five will prevent you from finding the last one (and therefore from finishing the quest), so you might wish to save the accept or take options until the book in the Forgotten Lair since you can only get the "positive" effects once.

Comment: Note that the friendship/rivalry modifiers only apply if Merril is in your party when you burn or read the tomes.

Comment: Sundermount, Viscounts Keep, Chantry, Bone Pit, and Wounded Coast - that's five. The additional tome (not tomb) in the Forgotten Lair would make _six_, not five.

Comment: @pablo, well spotted. Typo and spelling error fixed, thanks!